# Linear Layout Does not align baselines and Relative layout doesn't allow weights

Tags: android

I have a Linear layout with vertical orientation in which I'm inserting several view groups. One of them is:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/addedit_updowncontrol"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
   android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" 
   android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addedit_btndecrement"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:text="-" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/addedit_txtQuantity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="90dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addedit_btnIncrement"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/addedit_units"
        android:text="+" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/addedit_units"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This gives me a view that looks like [this](http://gmanish.x10.mx/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/LinearLayout.jpg) (apologies for the link, I wish there was a better way). This is unacceptable as the Button does not align with the EditText.

I tried switching to RelativeLayout, which gives me something like [this](http://gmanish.x10.mx/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/RelativeLayout.jpg). This is unacceptable as the two buttons (-) and (+) are not of the same width.

I guess what I'm trying to achieve is:
(1) The baseline of the Button is aligned with the other controls in the row.
(2) The two button are of the same width.

I seem to be able to achieve (1) with [RelativeLayout](http://gmanish.x10.mx/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/RelativeLayout.jpg) and (2) with [LinearLayout](http://gmanish.x10.mx/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/LinearLayout.jpg). But not both.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use

```
android:gravity="center_vertical"
```

in your linearlayout. All items will be centered

Comment: Thank you! this works and seems better than setting android:layout_marginTop="-3dp".

Comment: I do believe that this is a bug in the layout manager or whoever is responsible for the layout though.

Answer (score 1):

Change the orientation of Linear Layout to horizontal and set baselinealigned attribute to true in xml. Play with layout_weights. Assign the same weight to both buttons. Hope this helps

Comment: Baseline alignment is on by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can try several things. First set your LinearLayout Orientation horizontal. Have you tried to put the RelativeLayout inside the LinearLayout? Maybe this works too: set the buttons on wrap_content and the edit_text on fill_parent?

Comment: Just set the orientation of your LinearLayout at Horizontal. I tried it out and it worked for me

Comment: also try to set the margintop of your edittext a little higher. android:layout_marginTop(5dip) or some other integer that might work

Comment: Setting the LinearLayout to horizonal is not working for me. I still have the alignment problem. I've tried using a negative android:layout_marginTop like so: android:layout_marginTop="-3dp". This does align the button with the EditText. However, I'm not sure if this is going to be device independent.

Answer (score 0):

You've specified a lot of useless attributes for `LinearLayout`. E.g., you do not need all these `layout_alignParentTop`, `layout_toLeftOf` and so on [for LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html), they are used [in RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html). Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   android:id="@+id/addedit_updowncontrol"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" 
   android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
   android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addedit_btndecrement"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="-" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/addedit_txtQuantity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:minWidth="90dp"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addedit_btnIncrement"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="+" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/addedit_units"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I know, I'm sorry about that. I've been switching between layouts to see if I can find one that works. As far as I can tell, the one's that are not relevant are ignored. But I'll try cleaning up and see if that fixes anything.

Comment: I've already done it for you. I've also fixed your layout, just try it.

Comment: Thank you. I got it. Basically setting android:gravity="center_vertical" seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I know its not great, but keep the LinearLayout and put paddingTop="2dp" or marginTop="2dp" on the EditText and Spinner.

The 9patch assets for these elements include padding at the bottom that makes them look like they are out of line with everything else.

(I think its 2dp, it might be 3dp)

Not sure if this is still an issue for EditText on in 3.0+ since the stock designs for EditText are quite different in the holo theme